# Install WLE 2011 movie maker without updating Messenger?

Tags: windows-live, windows-movie-maker, video-editing

Is it possible to install Movie Maker without updating my messenger version (2009), or to revert to the previous version once it's updated?

[image]

If none is possible, what's a lightweight and simple video editing program for windows?

Answer (score 1):

I don't blame you for not wanting to update to the new messenger version. But that's no the the thing here.

Have a look at [Windows Movie Maker 2.6](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d6ba5972-328e-4df7-8f9d-068fc0f80cfc&displaylang=en), the last-but-one version before Windows Live Movie Maker. 2.7 is what came with XP but only 2.6 is avalible as a stand-alone download.

I know that it says for Vista but it runs just fine on XP and 7.

Comment: I tried 2.6 but it's messing with the sound quality of the music I use.